# How to implement session for the user logged in GRAILS( Spring security)?

Tags: session, grails, spring-security

HOW to implement session for the user logged in

THIS IS THE CODE I HAVE IMPLEMENTED

```
 def user=User.findByUserId(params.userId)
    if(user)
   {   
    def sessionUser=user
    def sessionId=sessionUser.id                       
    constSessionUser=sessionUser
    constSessionId=sessionId
  ..........
  }
```

But if I login using different username and password still the params.userId returned   is of previous user even though i have terminated it with session.invalidate()

since iam using Springsecurity i just pass username and password but the session created is still of the PREVIOUS USER OR ANY OTHER USER WHO HAS CURRENTLY REGISTERED !

1)HOW DO I CREATE A SESSION FOR THE USER LOGGED IN USING SPRING SECURITY SINCE

```
   def user=User.findByUserName(params.username)
```

is also leading to the same problem

2)HOW DO I TERMINATE A SESSION SO THAT SAME SESSION IS NOT IN PROCESS EVEN IF DIFFERENT USER HAS LOGGED IN

Any help will be truly appreciated plz...As iam new to Grails...

Comment: Could you please update your question to more readable format? I mean change UPPERCASE TEXT to normal.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use session, or track user manually, if you're using Spring Security plugin. When you need, you can access user details through `SpringSecurityService` ([see docs](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/6%20Helper%20Classes.html#6.2%20SpringSecurityService)), like:

```
class MyController() {

  SpringSecurityService springSecurityService


  def me() {    
     render model: [user: springSecurityService.currentUser]
  }
}
```